# How many fields are there (Up to isomorphism) with exactly 6 elements?

Tags: finite-fields

How many fields are there (Up to isomorphism) with exactly 6 elements?
In case of Group of order 6.. number of group( up to isomorphism )is 2..but what is it in case of field?

Comment: 0...............

Comment: Also, please do some research before posting. The second google hit for "finite field order" is the question I linked to above, and the first hit is a Wikipedia article that cites the exact same result....

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen ♦ ; why my flags does not count ? I have raised too many flags but it's about a week none of them has been counted, what's wrong with my account?

Comment: I don't know @Famke. The last one I see in your flagging history is dated August 26. I will check with the other mods. May be they know something I don't?

Comment: @Famke: A piece of news from a fellow mod. A user with 3k rep no longer casts close flags. They are automatically converted to votes to close.

Answer (score 4):

The order of a finite field must be a power of a prime, so there are no fields with $6=2\times3$ elements.

Comment: You might want to add that all finite fields with given order are isomorphic.